# Convert ComboBox selection event to Checkbox toggle

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox that has a check box and a text block inside it.

I would like that when an item in the ComboBox is selected, the state of CheckBox contained by the ComboBox item is toggled.

I have looked a fair bit here and elsewhere on the internet but I didn’t find anything specific to this.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="Wrapper"> <!-- CheckBox are good too -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheString}" />
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Wrapper, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You just have to rewrite the template for the the "Wrapper" `ToggleButton` (or `CheckBox`) so that it only shows its content.

I hope I was helpful.